# calculating the number of string occurances in another string

Tags: java, string

This is my assignment. I am not allowed to use `if` statements.

Write   a   program NumStrings.java that    receives    two strings through the command line    as
input   and then    prints  out the number  of  times   the second  string  occurs  as  a   substring   in  the 
first.

My bad code:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "HelloHelloHelloHello";
        String b = "Hello";
        int times = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <= a.length()-5; i++){
            for (int z=4; z<=(a.length()-1) && a.compareTo(b)==0; z++){
                times = times +1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(times);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has lots of problems. Also, you're not following the assignment. If this has to receive command line arguments then you have to use the `args` array.

Comment: i know but i want to test it initially with a simpler code

Comment: When `a = "ZZZ"` and `b = "ZZ"`, it should return 1 or 2?

Comment: it should print 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it, using `subString()` (documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

```
String a = "HelloHelloHelloHello";
String b = "Hello";
int times = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - b.length(); i++) {
    String substring = a.subString(i, i + b.length());
    if (substring.equals(b)) {
        times = times + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(times);
```

And here is a way to do it without `if` statements... Which I don't recommend. But if you have to do it that way, this will work.

```
String a = "HelloHelloHelloHello";
String b = "Hello";
int times = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - b.length(); i++) {
    String substring = a.substring(i, i + b.length());
    for (int j = 0; substring.equals(b) && j < 1; j++) {
        times = times + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(times);
```

Comment: im having trouble with another question, i am required to edit a string but we still didnt learn that in class yet i have it due in 5 hours ;$

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba You should ask a new question for that. It depends on how and when you need to modify it and where the result should be stored.

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba But also, I am sure that if you search questions that have already been asked, you will find someone that has already asked such a question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: you don't have to count how often you find the *second* string in the *first* String, because you always have to check **if** you found it or not. So, to avoid all sorts of conditions or if statements, consider using `firstString.split(secondString)`.

`split(someString)` will return you an array of *remaining* substrings once you "split" the base string everytime it finds your substring:

```
String first = "bababa";
String second = "a";
String[] substrings = first.split(second);
```

now `substrings` will look like this: `["b", "b", b"]` because every `a` has been *removed* and the rest put in separate Strings.

Next you have to check the size of the array and you'll see how often your `first` String was split.

```
int count = substrings.length;   // 3
```

However, this is not the end of it because we still have the following case:

```
 String first = "bababaa";
```

With the above solution you would get an array of size 3:  `["b", "b", "b"]`. The last occurrence of `a` will only be *removed* without leaving any substring behind (not even an empty one `''`).

So you can take advantage of another (slightly different) `split()`:

```
  first.split(second, limit);
```

Where `limit` is the maximum number of occurrences the method tries to find. So how often can you find your second string in the first one? As many letters the first string has: `int limit = first.length`

```
 first.split(second, first.length);  // will produce [b, b, b, , ]
```

Can you see what happens? there are two empty strings at the end where there where two `a`. You get an array of substrings for everything that is found *before* or *after* the occurrence of the second String.

Naturally, when you split the string `ba` you would get `["b", ]` so 2 substrings. But you don't care about the `b` just the "*commas*" in the middle (for every `a` a `,`).

```
 first.split(second, first.length).length -1;   // that's how many commas there are, and thats how many second strings there are
```

**EDIT**
(thanks @saka1029 !) So, the "split" method still misses something when `first="aaa"` and `second="aa"` because it counts only 1 not 2 occurrences.
To correct that I thought of looping through the whole first string and checking only for the very first occurrence, and then removing the first letter and continuing (*since OP already accepted another answer, I just post my code*):

```
  String first = "ZZZ";
  String second = "ZZ";
  int counter = 0;           // counts the number of occurrences
  int n = first.length();    // needs to be fixed, because we'll change the length of the first string in the loop
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){  // check the first string letter by letter
      String[] split = first.split(second, 2);  // we want one substring and the rest (2 in total) like: ['', 'Z'] when we cut off the first 'ZZ'
      counter += split.length - 1;  // now add the number of occurrences (which will be either 0 or 1 in our case)
      first = first.substring(1);   // cut off the first letter of the first string and continue
   }
   System.out.println("counter = " + counter);  // now we should get 3 for 'ZZZ'
```

Comment: It returns 1 instead of 2 for `first="ZZZ"` and `second = "ZZ"`.

Comment: oh! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @saka1029: I know it's too late for that, but what do you think of this? Can you find another problem?